# Drawing Bunch of Lines To Visualbasic Picturebox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datagridview, draw, picturebox

I have thousands of x and y coordinates in a datagridview, and i need to draw lines with them. for instance row 1, cell 1 contains x, row 1 cell 2 contains y and goes on. i need to draw from row 1 to 2, row 2 to 3. must be like a design. i used For i = 1 to 1000 for instance. and i used drawline function.

```
 Dim bmp As New Drawing.Bitmap(640, 480)
 Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim prcoordx As Integer
 Dim prcoordy As Integer
 Dim nextcoordx As Integer
 Dim nextcoordy As Integer   
 For i = 1 To 1000 Step 1
                prcoordx = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
                prcoordy = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
                nextcoordx = DataGridView1.Rows(i+1).Cells(1).Value
                nextcoordy = DataGridView1.Rows(i+1).Cells(2).Value

   Next i

   gfx.DrawLine(Pens.Black, prcoordx, prcoordy, nextcoordx, nextcoordy)
```

Comment: Your are going to be flagged and your question will be locked because : _"What is your question ?"_ - I mean, I know what is the question, but the literal formulation of your issue _("I don't know why...")_ and the explanation of the issues _("Can't get the <result you want>...")_ must be plain written in your post (but not only in the title)

Comment: What you've done : create a bitmap, create an object to be able to draw on that bitmap, doing a loop to read 1000-times values in a DataGridView **but not using them**, drawing **one single line** on the Bitmap : **the one that can be drawn using the last retrieved points** in DGV. - You have at least two possible issues, and your title **only cover one of it**.